# Characterization of smallest $\sigma$-Algebra on $\Omega=[0,1)$ that contains disjoint intervals of the form $[a,b)$ where $0<a<b<1$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> **Problem**: Let $\Omega$=[0,1) and $0=a_0 < a_1< \dots < a_n =1$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ 
>   Let $X:= \lbrace [a_{i-1}, a_i) : i =1,2, \dots , n \rbrace$ and find an identity for $\sigma(X)$ the smallest $\sigma$ Algebra on $\Omega$ that contains $X$

**My approach**: I claim that $$\sigma( X) = \mathcal{B}([0,1)) = \sigma ( \lbrace A \subset [0,1) : A \text{ is open} \rbrace ) $$
the Borel-Sigma Algebra

For ''$\subset$'' notice that  $X \in \mathcal{B}([0,1))$ because $[a_{i-1},a_i) \subset [0,1)$ for all $i =1, \dots , n$ and since $\sigma(X)$ denotes the smallest sigma algebra containing $X$ I conclude that $\sigma(X) \subset \mathcal{B}([0,1))$

For ''$\supset$'' I get confused by the notion of open, I suppose that in the context of sigma Algebras the set $[0,1)$ is open otherwise $\mathcal{B}([0,1))$ couldn't be the Borel Sigma algebra on $[0,1)$  (is that true?)

I have to consider an arbitrary open subset of $[0,1)$ in my Borel Sigma Algebra $\mathcal{B}([0,1))$ and show that I can write it as elements of $\sigma(X)$. But now I am lost of what counts as an open subset of $[0,1)$. If it is just $(a,b)$ where $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$ then I would argue that such an element can be written as $$(a,b)= \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}[a + 1/n,b) \in \sigma(X) $$
where $1/n < b-a$ and conclude the proof.

However I am having serious doubts that my argumentation is cyclic or not complete. Can somebody tell me if my ideas for $\supset$ are correct and where I am missing rigorous statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your claim is not correct. $\sigma(X)$ is a finite $\sigma$-algebra; in particular it does not equal the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra.

More precisely, $\sigma(X)$ has $2^n$ elements. Each element $A \in \sigma(X)$ admits a decomposition of the form $$A = \bigcup_{i \in I} [a_{i-1},a_i)$$ where $I \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a finite subset.

Comment: So what I presume to be right is that I have $\emptyset, E \in \sigma(X)$ also I must allow that $X \in \sigma(X)$ because it is the smallest sigma Algebra that contains $X$, what is left to do is to make these elements $\cup$-stable and complement stable. 

Therefore I'd say that $$\sigma(X)= \lbrace \emptyset, E, X, X^c \rbrace $$ because $X \cup E = E$

Comment: What I don't understand is that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so why is the set $\sigma(X)$ finite?

Comment: @Matriz $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a fixed number; so $2^n$ is also a finite number.

Comment: @Spaced Note that $X$ is a family of sets; therefore $X \in \sigma(X)$ doesn't make sense. $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ such that $B \in \mathcal{A}$ for any $B \in X$. So, here $B= [a_{i-1},a_i)$ for some $i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @saz, I think to understand this now, following the same idea as I had in my previous comment I would have $B_i:= [a_{i-1},a_i) \in \sigma(X)$ for all $i=1, \dots , n$ therefore I also need to investigate their union (they are disjoint) and their complements. By the characterization of elements of $\sigma(X)$ you have given in your post denoted as $A$ I would obtain that $$\sigma(X) = \lbrace \emptyset, E, A, A^c \rbrace $$

Comment: @Spaced .... but there is not only one set $A$ of this form, but several ones. As I have mentioned in  my answer, $\sigma(X)$ consists of $2^n$ elements.

Comment: @saz I do understand that there is not just one $A$ of this form, you have clearly written that we have $I \subset \lbrace 1, \dots , n \rbrace$ but I wouldn't know how to compress all this information in a clean way. I will probably use the notation $B_i= [a_{i-1},a_i)$ for $i=1, \dots , n$ and investigate such intervals further. I hope this will make it clearer for me :)

Comment: @spaced $$\sigma(X) = \{A \subseteq [0,1); \exists I \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}: A =\bigcup_{i \in I} [a_{i-1},a_i)\}.$$ (for $I = \emptyset$, we have by definition, $\bigcup_{i \in I} [a_{i-1},a_i) = \emptyset$.)

Answer (score 0):

$\sigma(X)$ is the collection of sets that can be written as a union of elements in $X$.

This union must allowed to be empty, resulting in $\varnothing\in\sigma(X)$.